# Suppose that $T^k = I$ for some positive integer k. Show that $T$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

Let $T: X \to X$ an operator in the complex space X. Suppose that $T^k = I$ for some positive integer k. Show that $T$ is diagonalizable.

I know that $T^k - I = 0$ $\implies$ $p(T) = 0$ for $x^k -1 = p(x)$, so m(x) = $x^n -1$ is a minimal polynomial for n$\leq$k.

I'm a little bit stuck after that, i don't know if i'm going in the right direction.

Comment: How many roots does this polynomial have? Are there equal roots?

Comment: For a complex space it has n roots, and all of them are distinct, right? So i'm basically done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial $p(x) = x^k - 1$ has $k$ distinct roots in $\Bbb{C}$ (i.e splits over $\Bbb{C}$ and each root has algebraic multiplicity $1$). Since the minimal polynomial $m_T(x)$ divides the annihilating polynomial $p(x)$, it follows that $m_T(x)$ also splits over $\Bbb{C}$, and each root has algebraic multiplicity $1$. This is equivalent to $T$ being diagonalizable (there are many proofs of this equivalence online and on this site as well).

---

By the way, it is not true that the minimal polynomial is of the form $x^n -1$ for some $n \leq k$. For instance, let $T=-\text{id}$, and let $p(x) = x^2 - 1$. Then, clearly $p(T) = 0$, but the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $m_T(x) = x+1$ (if what you wrote is true, the minimal polynomial would have to be either $x^2 -1$ or $x-1$, and this is false).

Comment: How could i write $m_T(x)$ then?

Comment: @Vityôk it doesn't matter. $m_T$ divides $p$, and that's all that is needed for this argument to work.

Comment: I understood that. I just wanted to know if there was a right way to write $m_T$, and how it is.

Comment: @Vityôk given the information we have, it is not possible to say what $m_T$ is (there can be many linear transformations $T$ which can satisfy $p(T) = 0$, and all of them can have different minimal polynomials)

Comment: one possibility to determine the minimal polynomial is to first find the Jordan canonical form (which always exists over $\Bbb{C}$), and then go from there (but again, this requires additional information). but unfortunately I can't think of any other methods right now